# How to use the Riemann sum for a line integral

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Let us say that we have the function $f(x,y) = xy$ and the curve $C: x=\cos(t), y=\sin(t)$ on the interval $[0, \pi/2]$. I want to use the Riemann sum to find out the integral of $$\int_{t=0}^{t=\frac{\pi}{2}} f(r(t))\left | r'(t) \right | dt $$

Geometrically, I can see that we want to multiply the function $f(x(t),y(t))$ by $ds$ and sum all of the parts to find our surface area.

I know that this integral evaluates as $\frac{1}{2}$. I can only assume that the summation we are dealing with is $ \displaystyle\sum_{t=0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left | \cos\left(\frac{t\pi}{2n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{t\pi}{2n}\right) \right |$ but I'm not clear of the details.